# im getting this error " ReviewCont : List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

Tags: knowledge

```
public class ReviewCont
{
   public String p_id;
   public product2 prod{set;get;}
   public Attachment at{set;get;} 
   public Boolean show{set;get;}
   public Boolean showt{set;get;}
   public String name{set;get;}
   public String email{set;get;}
   public String comment{set;get;}
   public List<Review__c> review_list{set;get;}
  public ReviewCont()
  {

  p_id= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

  prod= [select id,name,Description,Price__c,Type_New__c from product2 where id=:p_id];
  System.debug('------------------------------------------------'+prod);

  show= prod.Type_New__c    =='HOTEL'?true:false;
  showt=prod.Type_New__c    =='HOSPITAL'?true:false;

  at=[Select id,name,parentid from Attachment where parentid =:p_id];


  }
```

Comment: Hi Rishi, Debug p_id and see what you are getting in that.. if you are getting an sfid and see the record and make it's a product.. to see the record just put the sfid after your instance Url.... thanks.. Also , when you open the record check for the attachment.. whether it has attachment or not..

Answer (score 1):

You will get this exception whenever the SOQL query return zero records and you assign the query result directly to an instance of sObject.

It is best practice to assign every SOQL query to a list and based on the size of list you can do your operation. In this way you can avoid this exception.

So change the declaration of the product2 and attachment variable as

```
public List<product2> prod{set;get;}
public List<Attachment> at{set;get;}
```

After you query the required information check whether it is not null and its size greater than 0 and do your processing

```
if(prod != NULL && prod.size() > 0) {
    // do your processing
}
```

Hope it helps.